# How to have custom colors in ng2-charts and chart.js according to data?

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts, ngx-charts

I'm looking to build a line graph and mark all points above a certain value as red, and all those below that value as blue. I tried doing so with ngx-chart but that did not work. How do I do so with ng2-charts? Is that even possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the option [`pointBackgroundColor`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#point-styling) on the `dataset` as an array of colors for each point. To do so, you could use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as follows:

```
pointBackgroundColor: this.data.map(v => v > 60 ? "red" : "blue"),
```

This basically draws red points for values above 60, blue points otherwise.

Please take a look at this [**CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-hypatia-uw9iz?file=/src/app/app.component.ts) and see how it works.

Comment: Hey you solved my question. I have one doubt tho.. when I try to console.log the pointBackgroundColor[] inside my `ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.chartData.pointBackgroundColor)
  }`  i get the following error: `Property 'pointBackgroundColor' does not exist on type 'ChartDataset<keyof ChartTypeRegistry, (number | ScatterDataPoint | BubbleDataPoint)[]>[]'`. Why does this happen? And how do I solve this?

Comment: I don't know really, `ChartDataset` may not be in sync with the underlying Chart.js code. You could use the following instead: `console.log(this.chartData[0]['pointBackgroundColor'])`

Comment: Yes this works. However, when I try `console.log(this.chartData[0].pointBackgroundColor)`, angular shows the same error. Do you have any idea for the reason behind this discrepancy? Both of the syntaxes mean the same right? So in my mind, both should work? Also, if I want to do the same for BAR and Line chart without points, whats the property pf ChartDataset to which I should bind my array of colours to?

Comment: I guess that in the first case, the compiler complains because `pointBackgroundColor` is not defined on `ChartDataset`. In the second case, the compiler does not check if the property really exists, hence these cases are different. When it comes to `bar` charts and `line` charts without points, try to use the properties `backgroundColor` and `borderColor`.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<canvas baseChart width="400" height="360"
        [data]="chartData"
        [options]="chartOptions"
        [type]="chartType">
</canvas>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartConfiguration, ChartType } from 'chart.js';
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts';

export class MyChartComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) chart?: BaseChartDirective;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  public chartData: ChartConfiguration['data'] = {
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [10, 32, 21, 48],
        label: 'My Data',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        pointBorderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
        pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        fill: 'origin',
      },
    ],
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
  };

  public chartOptions: ChartConfiguration['options'] = {
    elements: {
      line: {
        tension: 0.5
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {},
      y: {
        position: 'left',
        beginAtZero: true,
        grid: {
          color: 'rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3)',
        },
        ticks: {
          color: '#666'
        }
      },
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    plugins: {
      legend: { display: true },
    }
  };

  public chartType: ChartType = 'line';
}
```

You only have to change these sample colors to your own ones.